# How to write a constructor with exception

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I want to know how can I write a constructor with exception in it

I have a class `Character`
and another class `Matrix<T>`

```
template<class T>
 class Matrix
 {
     T** data;
     int col;
     int row;
     public:
//ctor of matrix
 template<class T>
Matrix(const Matrix<T>& mat):data(new T*[mat.row]), col(mat.col), row(mat.row)
{
    
}
};
```

and then I have class Game:

```
class Game
{ 
    private:
    Matrix<std::shared_ptr<Character>> data;
    int height;
    int width;
    
    
    
public:
//ctor of Game, and the one I want to know how to write
    Game(int height, int width) :height(height),width(width)
    {
        try
        {
            data(Matrix<std::shared_ptr<Character>>(height,width));
        }
        catch(const std::badalloc&)
        {
           throw IllegalArgument();
        }
        
    }
```

the way I wrote the ctor for `Game` above is not correct, does anyone know how can I write it correctly and still check if it's allocated correctly ,

so in order to be allocated correctly the `height` and the `width` must be bigger than zero, but I couldn't find any way of how to check them first and then initialize data, which is why I am trying to use `try` and `catch`,but it's not correct, so does anyone know of a way to write the constructor, and make sure the allocate success???????????????(((using exceptions)))

`

Comment: I have yet to figure out what your actual question is...

Comment: If you want to check if `height > 0 && width > 0`, the code would be `if ( height > 0 && width > 0 )`... but I suspect that is not what you are asking...

Comment: You can pick off some things, like negative sizes or sizes that are obviously too large, but at the end of the day they only way to reliably detect an out of memory condition is to run out of memory. Even if you query the system to get the largest free block available, there's no good way to guarantee that no one else takes or shrinks that free block between the test and the request.

Comment: @user4581301: That's platform-specific, and pretty advanced for what I suspect is a simple confusion about some detail of constructor / exception mechanics...

Comment: What's platform specific, the thing I said isn't worth trying anyway?

Comment: @user4581301: There are platforms where an out of memory condition is perfectly well-defined and easily / reliably handled. That e.g. Linux is not able to satisfy the behavior specified by C/C++ for that condition is a problem of the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who needs it the solution is:

```
 Game(int height, int width):data((height<=0)||(width<=0) ? throw IllegalArgument() : Dimensions(height,width))
    ,height(height),width(width)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check if `height>0&&width>0` before initializing the data that needs allocating

Using a function:

```
class Game
{ 
    // ...
    static Matrix<std::shared_ptr<Character>>
    init_data(int height, int width)
    {
        if (height <= 0 || width <= 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("naughty dimensions");
        return {height, width};
    }
    
    
public:
    Game(int height, int width) :
        data(init_data(height, width)),
        height(height),
        width(width)
    {}
```

This way the member is never initialised unless provided dimensions are valid.

---

Other considerations:

- Bare owning pointers such as those in `Matrix` are bad. You should avoid them. One consequence of using them is that the cosntructor of `Matrix` is not exception safe. It will leak memory if creation of `T`s throws.
- It appears to be redundant to store the dimensions both inside `Matrix` and inside `Game`.